# Fetching data from API gives TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Tags: python, api, dictionary

I am trying to prototype business data analysis application in Python 2.7. The code is:

```
import urllib2
import json

url = 'http://dev.c0l.in:8888'
api = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = json.load(api)

for item in data:
    print item[{'sector':'technology'}]
```

It has to get the data from API and print out names of technology companies only. Instead of that I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gniteckm\Desktop\all2.py", line 9, in <module>
    print item[{'sector':'technology'}]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Comment: `item` is a dictionary; what are you trying to do? JSON object keys can only be *strings* anyway.

Comment: `dict` type is unhashable and you can not use it like index , whats the `data` look like ?

Comment: Are you trying to get data or update the data dict ?

Comment: @TanveerAlam: judging by the sentence *print out names of technology companies only* they are trying to *get* data.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes i almost got that he is trying to print data but by just seeing the {} expression, I got eager to know whether is really want to print or is trying to update first and then some operation. Thanks

Comment: I've made an *educated guess* as to what your data looks like; can you provide us with an actual sample of a JSON response so we can give you better advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot filter dictionaries; they don't take a query. You'll have ta pass in keys that actually exist in the `item` dictionaries, and because this is JSON, `item` will only have string keys.

You can filter on specific key-value pairs with an `if` statement:

```
for item in data:
    if item['sector'] == 'technology':
        print item
```

This assumes that all `item` dictionaries in `data` have a `'sector'` key. If not, use `dict.get()` to return a default if the key is missing:

```
for item in data:
    if item.get('sector') == 'technology':
        print item
```